# Ruby Cucumber AfterStep not running after every step in a scenario

Tags: ruby, cucumber, automated-tests, hook, bdd

I'm using Cucumber with Ruby and I want to execute some code after each step of the scenario. I have implemented the AfterStep hook, but I have found that it is not running after every step.

```
AfterStep do |step|
  puts "After step"
end
```

Is there any reason why Cucumber wouldn't run this hook after a particular step in the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running cucumber 0.3.11 and the scenario has a background, the [documentation](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Hooks#step-hooks) indicates that an `AfterStep` hook will not work:

```
Warning: AfterStep hook does not work with scenarios which have backgrounds
(cucumber 0.3.11)

AfterStep do |scenario|
  # Do something after each step.
end
```

Comment: This is the extract from the Gemfile.lock:

`cucumber (2.0.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
      cucumber-core (~> 1.2.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3)
      gherkin (~> 2.12)
      multi_json (>= 1.7.5, < 2.0)
      multi_test (>= 0.1.2)
    cucumber-core (1.2.0)
      gherkin (~> 2.12.0)`

When I run the test with `puts "After step"` in the AfterStep block it seems to print it put for half the steps but not for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

check your file path.For example, if the code are put in a file named `hooks.rb` , the file' path should be `features/support/hooks.rb`.